# jQuery take value and insert into dropdown menu and add url as option value

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that is automatically generated, I want jQuery code help me to take out the value inside the div and add into a dropdown menu, and add "/listing-agent-staff/barack-obama" as option value.

**the auto generated code:**

```
<div class="StaffName">Barack Obama</div>
<div class="StaffName">Bill Clinton</div>
<div class="StaffName">Will Smith</div>
```

**the dropdown menu I want the value to be inserted to:**

```
<label for="Listing_Agent_Staff">Listing Contact</label>
<select name="Listing_Agent_Staff" id="Listing_Agent_Staff" class="cat_dropdown">
<option value="">-- Please select --</option>
<option value="/listing-agent-staff/barack-obama">Barack Obama</option>
<option value="/listing-agent-staff/bill-clinton">Bill Clinton</option>
<option value="/listing-agent-staff/will-smith">Will Smith</option>
</select>
```

**please note the first part is generated automatically so the number of record varies, the number of options in the second part should cope with that. Thank you.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
​$(".StaffName")​​​​​​​​.each(function () {
   var name = $(this).text();
   var value = "/listing-agent-staff/" + name.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "-");
   $("<option>").text(name).attr("value", value).appendTo("#Listing_Agent_Staff");
}​);​
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twGUL/)**.

Answer (score 2):

```
var options = '';

$('.StaffName').each(function() {
    var val = $.text(this),
        url = val.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
    options += '<option value="/listing-agent-staff/' + url + '">' + val + '</option>';
});

$('#Listing_Agent_Staff').append(options);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MCKZ7/

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is iterate over all the `StaffName` elements and append the apropriate HTML to the select.

```
$.each('.StaffName',function(index,elem){
  var oldValue = $(elem).text().toLowerCase();
  var optionValue = '/listing-agent-staff/' + oldValue.replace(' ','-');
  $("#Listing_Agent_Staff").append('<option value="'+ optionValue +'">'+ $(elem).text() +'</option>';
});
```

What we are doing here is iterating over all the `.StaffName` elements and for each one, extracting it's text value.  That value is then [converted to lower case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) and all the spaces are [replaced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with dashes.  This is to create the URL.  Then we use the [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function to add additional HTML content to the `#Listing_Agent_Staff` element.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with the previous answer that it would be ideal to do this on the server side.  If that won't work, the following should take care of it:

```
$(function() {
  $('.StaffName').each(function(e) {
    var div = $(this);
    var href = '/listing-agent-staff/' + div.text().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');
    $('#Listing_Agent_Staff').append('<option value="' + href +'">' + div.text() + '</option>');
  });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hN67g/

Answer (score 0):

This would mean having js write new code. The best solution is to have the server side code (php?) write out the dropdown code as well.

Comment: thanks...uhm....due to some reason, the server side coding for me is untouchable, this is why i have to do this in jquery.